# How to Edit Excel files in VS Code using C#?

Tags: c#, com, visual-studio-code

I want to write to an Excel file. So I add " Microsoft Excel Object Library" through "COM Component" in Visual Studio, then there will be some code in "*.csproj":

```
</ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Core">
.................
.................
```

I can build this project in Visual Studio. But when I build it in VS Code, I get this error:

"C:\Program ## Heading ##Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.403\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2729,5): error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveComReference" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a. Confirm that the declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. "

Someone help me, please!

Comment: Do you really need to use the COM library?. You can use other libraries that are actually for the .net framework, like [interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel?view=excel-pia), [OpenXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) or [epplus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/)

Comment: @ikerbera: I'm a newbie, I just search on the internet and follow some tutorials for Visual Studio, but I can not do the same for VS Code. Thank you for your suggestion, I will check those things.

Comment: Check [this](https://itenium.be/blog/dotnet/create-xlsx-excel-with-epplus-csharp/) tutorial out for epplus. Also, get used to use [nuget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio), it can be very helpful and even more for a newbie. [This](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Getting-Started) epplus getting started guide can be a good read too.

Comment: @ikerbera: Thank you very much.